# Java: Reading a directory of partitioned parquet files

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet

I created a Parquet output from Apache Spark, hence a directory with multiple files, one per partition. Now I want to read that from Java.
(New API, many methods are deprecated today)

Reading a single file is okay:

```
HadoopInputFile file = HadoopInputFile.fromPath(new Path(nodeId), conf);
ParquetReadOptions options = ParquetReadOptions.builder().build();
try (ParquetFileReader reader = ParquetFileReader.open(file, options);) {
  MessageType schema = reader.getFileMetaData().getSchema();
}
```

If the file is a directory, the ParquetFileReader complains with "is a directory". Fine. So I need either a method that supports a directory or allows adding multiple files. This method should read all files and merge the schema.

My most recent experiment is

```
ParquetReadOptions options = ParquetReadOptions.builder().build();
ReadSupport readSupport = new GroupReadSupport();
ParquetReader r = ParquetReader.builder(readSupport, new Path(nodeId)).build();
SimpleGroup o = (SimpleGroup) r.read();
```

SimpleGroup has a schema, although not exposed, but I am sure I can go along that route.

But isn't there a simpler way?

A method that does expose a getFileMetaData().getSchema() method as well? That does not need to read a first record just to have a schema? That does create a merged schema?

Would appreciate any hints and examples...

Comment: Any updates on this issue?